# Is there a method to know if we can apply regression to certain dataset and obtain satisfactory results?

Tags: regression, dataset

I am working on 84 images, where each image is assigned a target value Y (could be any measure such as blur or noise level). Y is already known for all images. Features X (predictors) are extracted from each image. There are many methods for feature extraction, and most of them return large number of features. The problem turns to be a regression problem, where we need to predict Y given X (the features).

Having many methods to construct the features, I need a way to assess the ability of certain features to predict Y. I am thinking of using Support Victor Regression with Radial Basis kernel for prediction, I will also investigate other methods, such as decision trees and linear regression.

**My question is:** given a dataset, can we analyze the data and know if we can apply regression analysis on it and obtain good results (e.g. > 70% accuracy)? (Either linear or non-linear regression)

Please keep in mind that there are too many features, so analyzing the correlation between X and Y, and the multi-colinearity among X is infeasible, unless there is an automated way.